# How to find implicit usages of toString() method for specific type

Tags: java, tostring, static-analysis, findbugs

Recently I changed all places in my code where passwords were processed from `String` to a new `Password` class. The `Password.toString()` method now just prints `[********]`. If I want to get the password I have to call `Password.getPassword()`. This way I can be sure that no password will ever accidentally be written into log files.

During the change I missed to change some lines that look like this:

```
String.format( "user:%s", password );
```

Before my change `password` was of type `String`, so it was formatted as desired. But after my change `password` was rendered as `[*******]`. That's exactly what I intended. But now I would like to find all these places automatically.

I tried [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) with the [fb-contrib](https://github.com/mebigfatguy/fb-contrib) plugin ([ITU_INAPPROPRIATE_TOSTRING_USE](http://fb-contrib.sourceforge.net/bugdescriptions.html#ITU_INAPPROPRIATE_TOSTRING_USE)) but it did not find the implicit use of `Password.toString()` within String.format().

Does anybody know of another findbugs contrib project or any other static code analyzer that could find these code places?

Answer (score 0):

ITU only finds use of toString() which is used in which you are inferring the value of the content, say if you are parsing it for some value, or using it to build up some other string. The detector is there to let you know that really you shouldn't rely on the contents of toString() as it should be considered 'debugging' output, in many cases. (as you see here).

There would be way to many false positives just to check for uses of toString() which is always valid.

And no, don't know of any detectors, altho it would be pretty trivial to write one.